# How do I implement a "phonetical"-like search

Tags: c#, full-text-search

Currently I'm trying to enhance my search algorithm.

For better understanding, here's the current logic behind it:
we have objects with attached n keywords in db. in database this is solved via 2 tables (`Object`, `Keyword`) where the `Keyword`-table has a FK to `Object`. When i'm building my searchtrees I create a line-value (ad: remove umlauts, convert to lower-case, ...) of all keywords of an object. the same convertion-routine (`NormalizeSearchPattern()`) is done with the search-patterns. I'm supporting `AND`-search and keywords with minimum length of 2 characters only!

The search-algorithm is currently a variant of `fast-reverse-search` (this example is not optimized):

```
bool IsMatch(string source, string searchPattern)
{
    // example:
    // source: "hello world"
    // searchPattern: "hello you freaky funky world"
    // patterns[]: { "hello", "you", "freaky", "funky", "world" }

    searchPattern = NormalizeSearchPattern(searchPattern);
    var patterns = MagicMethodToSplitPatternIntoPatterns(searchPattern);
    foreach (var pattern in patterns)
    {
        var success = false;
        var patternLength = pattern.Length;
        var firstChar = pattern[0];
        var secondChar = pattern[1];

        var lengthDifference = input.Length - patternLength;
        while (lengthDifference >= 0)
        {
            if (source[lengthDifference--] != firstChar)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (source[lengthDifference + 2] != secondChar)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var l = lengthDifference + 3;
            var m = 2;
            while (m < patternLength)
            {
                if (input[l] != pattern[m])
                {
                    break;
                }
                l++;
                m++;
            }

            if (m == patternLength)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }
        if (!success)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Normalization is done with (this example is not optimized)

```
    string RemoveTooShortKeywords(string keywords)
    {
        while (Regex.IsMatch(keywords, TooShortKeywordPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
            keywords = Regex.Replace(keywords, TooShortKeywordPattern, " ", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        }

        return keywords;
    }

    string RemoveNonAlphaDigits(string value)
    {
        value = value.ToLower();
        value = value.Replace("ä", "ae");
        value = value.Replace("ö", "oe");
        value = value.Replace("ü", "ue");
        value = value.Replace("ß", "ss");

        return Regex.Replace(value, "[^a-z 0-9]", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    }

    string NormalizeSearchPattern(string searchPattern)
    {
        var resultNonAlphaDigits = RemoveNonAlphaDigits(searchPattern);
        var resultTrimmed = RemoveTooShortKeywords(resultNonAlphaDigits);
        return resultTrimmed;
    }
```

So this is pretty straight forward, thus it's obvious, that I can only cope with variants of `source` and `searchPattern` which I've implemented in `NormalizeSearchPattern()` (as mentioned above: umlauts, case-differences, …).

But how should I enhance the algorithm (or `NormalizeSearchPattern()`) to be non-sensitive when it comes down to:

- singular/plural
- misstyping (eg. "hauserr" <-> "hauser")
- ...

Just to know more about the design:
This app is done in c#, it stores the searchtrees and objects in a static variable (to query the database only once at init), the performance has to be outstanding (currently 500.000 lineValues are queried within less than 300msec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also be interested in a [Trigram and Bigram search matching algorithm](http://www.webology.ir/2006/v3n4/a35.html):

> Trigram search is a powerful method of searching for text when the exact syntax or spelling of the target object is not precisely known. It finds objects which match the maximum number of three-character strings in the entered search terms, i.e. near matches. A threshold can be specified as a cutoff point, after which a result is no longer regarded as a match.

Comment: You will need a dictionary to match against. Scanning wikipedia to get you a first dictionary draft is good enough. Then, split all these words into bi (2) or tri (3) grams. `Hello` will be: `hel`, `ell`, `llo`. When matching a word, split that too, so `Helllo` will be: `Hel`, `ell`, `lll`, and `llo`. Now calculate these matches, and sort them by relevance. `Helllo` will match on `Hello`, but it might also match on other words.

Comment: a certain fuzziness is unavoidable, as i requested it :) i could enhance the whole search-process to first use the old (sharp) algorithm and then, with a certain threshold, use the fuzzy algorithm!

Comment: Yeah indeed. You can also always test out other fuzzy matching algorithms ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should investigate the [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm.  It's an algorithm for converting words into a phonetic space, such that similar sounding words (and slightly misspelled) words map to the same (or similar) values.  There's a list of [other phonetic algorithms on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm):

> - Soundex, which was developed to
>     encode surnames for use in censuses.
>     Soundex codes are four-character
>     strings composed of one letter
>     followed by three numbers.
>
>   - Daitch–Mokotoff Soundex, which is a refinement of Soundex designed to
>       better match surnames of Slavic and
>       Germanic origin. Daitch–Mokotoff
>       Soundex codes are strings composed of
>       six numeric digits.
>   - Kölner Phonetik which is similar to Soundex, but more suitable for
>       German words.
>   - Metaphone and Double Metaphone, which is suitable for use with most
>       English words, not just names.
>       Metaphone algorithms are the basis for
>       many popular spell checkers.
>   - Miracode
>   - New York State Identification and Intelligence System (NYSIIS),
>       which maps similar phonemes to the
>       same letter. The result is a string
>       that can be pronounced by the reader
>       without decoding.
>   - Match Rating Approach developed by Western Airlines in 1977 - this
>       algorithm has an encoding and range
>       comparison technique.

Comment: an absolut nogo! these algos are creating an hash - how can a hash be searched??? eg. `source=" hello you lovely world "`, `patterns[]: { "ell" }`. this should match, as `ell` is part of `hello`...

Comment: My understanding of your question is also that it _is_ something like soundex that you need. How else could one resolve mis-typing and plurals as you request? (The moreso that your examples hint at more than one language). Maybe re-work your question?

Comment: @smirkingman: not necessarily soundex... i do not intend to accuse you, but it's maybe because of your limited knowledge of search-algorithms :) as a sidenode: the tri-/bigram-algorithm fits my conditions as well!

Comment: "because of your limited knowledge of search-algorithms" I'll give you the benefit of the doubt by assuming that English is not your mother tongue, and you're not half my age, but your remark is rude.

Comment: @smirkingman: that's why i've added a smiley and introduced this sentence with 'i do not ...' ... you simple take it in the wrong way (or did not get my sarcasm) ... sorry mate, did not mean to harm you! or maybe i'm just a rude guy :) ... btw... my knowledge is limited as well - otherwise i wouldn't ask this question, would i?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at something called [levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) it computes how many changes is required to change one word into another.

Few changes indicates very simliar words.

For plural matching you could also use alias tables if the plural form is vastly different from singular but you still want them to match. I assume Google uses some form of alias lists for their suggestions of alternate questions.