# Better way to check if a given word is "close" to other words in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, cpu-word

I am writing an algorithm that, given a word **spoken** by the user, finds the most similar variant of that word in a given array. For example let the given array be:

```
const givenArr = ["foo","bar","foobar"];
```

and my "spoken" word right now used for testing:

```
const currText = "foo"
```

Basically, I want to match the *currText* with an element in the *givenArr*. This example is simple, the words are the same. But the user speech and the overall reception may vary, so "foo" may be received as only "fo" or "for" thus the words don't match so simply.
This is my current solution:

```
givenArr.forEach((word) => {
    if (currText.length <= word.length + 1) {
        let foundMatch = 0;
        let buffWord = currText;
        word = word.split('');
        word.forEach((char) => {
            if (buffWord.includes(char)) {
                foundMatch++;
                buffWord = buffWord.slice(1);
            }
        });
        if (foundMatch >= word.length - 1) {
            let finalText = word.join(''); // get the fullword back.
            console.log(finalText)
        }
    }
});
```

The way it works is by checking how many chars are similar in every word in *givenArr* with *currText*. If most of them correlate then I found the closest element. I've manually tested it with my **needed** array (which is not big, maximum 10 words ) and it works, but the algorithm looks ugly and I belive is slow ( it takes somewhere between 2 - 3 ms to find it ). How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance might be what you want (or a similar edit-distance)

Comment: You'll fist have to define the rules of what is similar and what is not, in a very precise manner. These rules would be much different for non-English languages... Moreover you would need to recognise diphthongs, not just single letters, and `includes` seems to be the wrong method here as it could match a letter that might be one or more syllables away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about Levenshtein distance. But using it would be made the search faster? I am still going to test it, but I am curious.

Comment: Your current algorithm seems to remove the first letter of buffWord regardless of whether the first was the letter that matched.  I think Levenshtein will give you a more accurate search.  Whether it’s worth a few more ms (and you can easily test if it’s faster by implementing it and trying it) is going to be up to you and your requirements.  IMO 2-3ms is not slow in human terms.

Comment: Consider the **Levenshtein distance** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript

Comment: This might also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314043/how-do-i-implement-a-phonetical-like-search